# Append suffix to all files with a certain extension

Tags: filenames, rename

Write the command that will locate all files that have the suffix/extension of `.py`. For each file that is located, the command should append the suffix/extension of `.backup` to the file. So, if a file had the name `one.py`, its new name would be `one.py.backup`.

I tried

```
find . / -name "*.py" -type f -exec mv {} {}.backup \;
```

and it did not work

Comment: You have a small typo, probably you mean `find . -type f -name "*.py" -exec mv {} {}.backup \;` and if it doesn't work, please update the question with the exact error/reason.

Comment: it worked. thanks

Comment: Where are the files located? Only in the current directory, or also in sub-directories?

Answer (score 1):

A shell-based solution could also work, since the task here is easy enough (simply appending a string fragment to a filename)

```bsh
for file in *.py; do newname="$file.backup"; mv "$file" "$newname"; done
```

---

If it is possible that no such file exists, you would need to catch that case explicitly. Assuming `bash`, you could use the `nullglob` option:

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob; for file in *.py; do newname="$file.backup"; mv "$file" "$newname"; done
```

or test explicitly if the file exists:

```bsh
for file in *.py; do newname="$file.backup"; [ -f "$file" ] && mv "$file" "$newname"; done
```

---

If the files in question can also be in sub-directories, things get more complicated. With `bash` v4 onwards, you can use the `globstar` option:

```bsh
shopt -s globstar; for file in **/*.py; do newname="$file.backup"; mv "$file" "$newname"; done
```

Again, you may have to combine with `shopt -s nullglob` to account for the case no such file exists.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can start doing something like:

`> find PATH -name "*.py"`

where you can change the `PATH` to the desired folder you want to look for... and them you could pipe the output with another command like `mv` using `xargs`.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. Please note, however, that complete answers are preferred; you may want to expand your proposed solution with one of the methods you mention to make a full example out of your post.

Comment: @AdminBee ok... sorry for the incomplete answer.